# Microsoft dateformat add 1 to yyyy

Tags: date-format

If the current year is 2023, how do I display 2024 (next year) using Microsoft Date Format (yyyy).

I couldn't find anything in their documentation or in StackOverflow.

I tried to do `yyyy+1` and `(yyyy+1)` etc.

Thanks in advance!